# Laravel validating the uniqueness of a field only when the value is not null

Tags: php, laravel, validation, voyager

I have a system_name field that is nullable that I want to validate for uniqueness if the input is not null.

As based on the recommended solutions given by others, it can just be

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'system_name' => 'nullable|unique:systems'
]);
```

Why is it that this solution work? Given that when a null value is entered for system_name, shouldn't it pass the nullable rule but fail the unique rule as the null value is not unique since it has been used before?

Can I also enquire what is the difference between encapsulating the rule with '' vs [ ] ? As shown by the validation done on username and email

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
            'username' => 'required|min:8',
            'email' => ['required', Rule::unique('users')]
        ];
}
```

Comment: @TimLewis do you want to post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it ? Thanks for the explanation I cant find any information about this anywhere be it on the the laravel validation documentations or on stack overflow. 

Do you by any chance have a source to these information

Comment: Experience, mostly. The documentation for the rules is a little vague in that sense, but from working with Laravel for the last 7 years, I've seen plenty  And yes, I can convert to an answer; just a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-nullable) for the `nullable` rule simply states:

> The field under validation may be `null`.

What it doesn't state that if the field is `null`, the subsequent validation is ignored. So in your case, the `unique:systems` rule is not called. And from a logical standpoint, this makes sense, as a `nullable` column/index should not treat `null` as a unique value.<sup>1</sup>

Additionally, the difference between `'nullable|unique:systems'` and `['nullable', 'unique:systems']` (or other variants) is: nothing, really. In older versions of Laravel, the `'rule1|rule2'` syntax was the only method available. Compare the documentation for Laravel 5.4 and Laravel 6.x:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#basic-usage
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#basic-usage

The `6.x` version includes:

> Alternatively, validation rules may be specified as arrays of rules instead of a single `|` delimited string

Nowadays, both syntaxes are acceptable, mainly to support older versions for backwards compatibility, and syntax preference. I like the `|` delimited string, but the `[]` method is a bit more flexible (since you can use Rules and Functions as shown in some of the examples in the Documentation.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Typically; that might not be true for all DB types, but from my experience this is the case.

Comment: thanks for enlightening me :) hours of googling couldn't give me an answer to my questions